# How to display special characters in QT 5?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, utf-8, qt5

Excerpt from my code:

```
  char msg[80];
  sprintf(msg, "Chuck Temperature: %.1f °C", temperature);
  ui.TemperatureLabel->setText(QString::fromUtf8(msg));
```

What I get:

[image]

What does not work:

- Replacing the degree symbol (°) by &deg; while setting textFormat to RichText. It is displayed as "**Chuck Temperature: &deg;C**".
- Adding `QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));` did not help at all.

I work under Visual C++, if that is important.

Comment: Are you sure your source file is UTF-8 encoded? Are you sure your compiler supports UTF-8 encoded source files? It is recommended to use uniiversal character names in ""u8 strings to take these variables out of the equation.

Comment: how to use uniiversal character names in ""u8 strings  ?

Comment: Like this `"This is a degree character \u00B0"u8`.

Comment: Does your output font support that code point?

Comment: @n.m. - that did not help

Comment: Works for me (after I fix the stupid error, `u8` should be before the string, not after). Show a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

What about using a `QString` instead ? It handles for you the special characters.

If I understand your code, you want to update the text of a `QLabel`.

You could do something as follows:

```
QString msg("Chuck Temperature: " + QString::number(temperature) + " °C");
ui.TemperatureLabel->setText(msg);
```

Note that you can specify the desired precision in `QString::number()`. [Here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number-6) you can see how to do it.
If you want to format the temperature the same way as `%.1f` does, just write the following:

```
QString msg("Chuck Temperature: " + QString::number(temperature, 'g', 2) + " °C");
ui.TemperatureLabel->setText(msg);
```

I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Alas, it did not help.

Comment: @user31264 I don't understand what you did, because it works successfully for me. Perhaps it is your file that does not have a proper encoding.